# Run keras job with OpenAI Gym Atari on gcloud ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml, openai-gym

I'm having trouble running a keras+TF+GymAI Atari job on cloud ML engine. In particular, when using the Atari environment, do you need to pickle the data and put it in the storage bucket or can you run efficiently when you install Gym without actually storing the atari environments in the bucket?
I've been looking really hard and can't find any examples of configuration for OpenAI environments running on ML engine. I would appreciate some examples. To illustrate the current job submittal process, I have the following:

```
export BUCKET_NAME=atari_game_bucket
export JOB_NAME="atari_game_train_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
export JOB_DIR=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME
export REGION=us-east1

#submit job
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
--job-dir $JOB_DIR \
--runtime-version 1.0 \
--module-name trainer.ac3d \
--package-path ./trainer \
--region $REGION \
-- 

# the local model
import os
import gym
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import deque
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.transform import resize
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, Flatten, Dense


ENV_NAME = 'Breakout-v0'  # Environment name
FRAME_WIDTH = 84  
FRAME_HEIGHT = 84  
NUM_EPISODES = 12000  
STATE_LENGTH = 4  
GAMMA = 0.99  
EXPLORATION_STEPS = 1000000
...   
SAVE_NETWORK_PATH = 'saved_networks/' + ENV_NAME
SAVE_SUMMARY_PATH = 'summary/' + ENV_NAME
NUM_EPISODES_AT_TEST = 30  
class Agent():
    def __init__(self, num_actions):
```

Comment: CMLE doesn't have sample about OpenAI Gym currently. We would love to assist you to create such an sample. There are usually two issues when running a non-supported framework in Cloud: 1. not easy to make distributed training work 2. the non-supported framework has no ability to directly access GCS. I would suggest you start with single replica training with all the required data copied to VM first.